# Counting the amount of four letter sequences

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Given the following two strings of words: "Bobo, Mississippi" and "Soso, Mississippi", what is the difference in the amount of four letter sequences that can be formed by using theirs letters (excluding spaces and commmas)?

I believe each can be calculated by choosing 4 letters each time from the string.

For Bobo:
Let $x = b + o + m + i + s + p$, where each letter (except x) is the number of that letter in the given string.

Then I can do:

$\Sigma_{x=4} \frac{4!}{b!o!m!i!s!p!}$

What this should mean is, find the permutations of length 4 such that the letters are distributed to have the amount of letters summing to 4. Then add up the amount of permutations for each. However, I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to solve this.

I'm not even sure if this approach is correct. If there is another method to solving this that is easier, I would really appreciate if it were explained to me.

Comment: Hint: Since Mississippi in itself already has four `s`, every string that can be made with Soso can also be made with Bobo. So the problem is really asking for the number of strings that contain at least one `b`. And from there it seems to be easier to do an ad-hoc analysis for each of the cases "one `b`" and "two `b`s" than to develop a general formula.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I ended up calculating the amount of combinations that have 2 b's, and 1 b's since the b's would be the only strings that Bobo can create that Soso cannot. Then adding them together would give me the difference between using Bobo and Soso. This was a very helpful hint.

Comment: @user3370201 Did you arrive at the correct answer of 584?

Comment: @JKnecht I think that was the answer I got (or something very similar). I don't have it with me anymore because this was actually a homework question, and I had to pass it in.